# How to Reduce by key in "Scala" [Not In Spark]

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I am trying to reduceByKeys in Scala, is there any method to reduce the values based on the keys in Scala. [ i know we can do by reduceByKey method in spark, but how do we do the same in Scala ? ]

The input Data is :

```
val File = Source.fromFile("C:/Users/svk12/git/data/retail_db/order_items/part-00000")
                 .getLines()
                 .toList

 val map = File.map(x => x.split(","))
               .map(x => (x(1),x(4)))

  map.take(10).foreach(println)
```

After Above Step i am getting the result as:

```
(2,250.0)
(2,129.99)
(4,49.98)
(4,299.95)
(4,150.0)
(4,199.92)
(5,299.98)
(5,299.95)
```

Expected Result :

```
(2,379.99)
(5,499.93)
.......
```

Comment: I think this is missing a group-by step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, you can use the [`groupMapReduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) method which is (as its name suggests) an equivalent of a `groupBy` followed by `mapValues` and a `reduce` step:

```
io.Source.fromFile("file.txt")
  .getLines.to(LazyList)
  .map(_.split(','))
  .groupMapReduce(_(1))(_(4).toDouble)(_ + _)
```

The `groupMapReduce` stage:

- `group`s splited arrays by their 2nd element (`_(1)`) (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s each array occurrence within each group to its 4th element and cast it to `Double` (`_(4).toDouble`) (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s values within each group (`_ + _`) by summing them (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**).

This is a [one-pass version](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L604) of what can be translated by:

```
seq.groupBy(_(1)).mapValues(_.map(_(4).toDouble).reduce(_ + _))
```

Also note the cast from `Iterator` to `LazyList` in order to use a collection which provides `groupMapReduce` (we don't use a `Stream`, since starting `Scala 2.13`, `LazyList` is the recommended replacement of `Stream`s).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want the sum of some values from a file. One problem is that files are strings, so you have to cast the `String` to a number format before it can be summed.

These are the steps you might use.

```
io.Source.fromFile("so.txt") //open file
  .getLines()                //read line-by-line
  .map(_.split(","))         //each line is Array[String]
  .toSeq                     //to something that can groupBy()
  .groupBy(_(1))             //now is Map[String,Array[String]]
  .mapValues(_.map(_(4).toInt).sum) //now is Map[String,Int]
  .toSeq                     //un-Map it to (String,Int) tuples
  .sorted                    //presentation order
  .take(10)                  //sample
  .foreach(println)          //report
```

This will, of course, throw if any file data is not in the required format.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built-in, but you can write it like this:

```
def reduceByKey[A, B](items: Traversable[(A, B)])(f: (B, B) => B): Map[A, B] = {
  var result = Map.empty[A, B]
  items.foreach {
    case (a, b) =>
      result += (a -> result.get(a).map(b1 => f(b1, b)).getOrElse(b))
  }
  result
}
```

There is some space to optimize this (e.g. use mutable maps), but the general idea remains the same.

Another approach, more declarative but less efficient (creates several intermediate collections; can be rewritten but with loss of clarity:

```
def reduceByKey[A, B](items: Traversable[(A, B)])(f: (B, B) => B): Map[A, B] = {
  items
    .groupBy { case (a, _) => a }
    .mapValues(_.map { case (_, b) => b }.reduce(f))
    // mapValues returns a view, view.force changes it back to a realized map
    .view.force
}
```

Comment: It would be better to curry this function so that the compiler knows the type of `B` for the `f` parameter. Also, `fold` is preferable to `map/getOrElse`.

Comment: Yes, currying does make sense, but `fold` is a matter of taste :) I personally dislike that it looks like `fold(a)(_ + b)` rather than `fold(none = a, some = _ + b)` (like e.g. `cata` in scalaz).

Answer (score 1):

First group the tuple using key, first element here and then reduce.
Following code will work -

```
val reducedList = map.groupBy(_._1).map(l => (l._1, l._2.map(_._2).reduce(_+_)))
print(reducedList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution using a foldLeft:

```
val File : List[String] = ???

File.map(x => x.split(","))
  .map(x => (x(1),x(4).toInt))
  .foldLeft(Map.empty[String,Int]){case (state, (key,value)) => state.updated(key,state.get(key).getOrElse(0)+value)}
  .toSeq
  .sortBy(_._1)
  .take(10)
  .foreach(println)
```